# how do I chain the custom logic using scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to achieve the calculation of area of polygon using scala

Reference for Area of Polygon https://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html

I was able to write the code successfully but my requirement is I want the last for loop to be chained within points variable like other map logics. Map is not working because output of list is (N-1)

```
var lines=io.Source.stdin.getLines()
val nPoints= lines.next.toInt
var s=0
var points = lines.take(nPoints).toList map(_.split(" ")) map{case Array(e1,e2)=>(e1.toInt,e2.toInt)} 

 for(i <- 0 until points.length-1){    // want this for loop to be chained within points variable        
      s=s+(points(i)._1 * points(i+1)._2) - (points(i)._2 * points(i+1)._1)
    }



println(scala.math.abs(s/2.0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a `sliding` and a `foldLeft`, I think. `sliding(2)` will give you lists `List(i, i+1), List(i+1, i+2),...` and then you can use `foldLeft` to do the computation:

```
val s = points.sliding(2).foldLeft(0){ 
  case (acc, (p1, p2)::(q1, q2)::Nil) => acc + p1*q2 - p2*q1 }
```

If I read the formula correctly, there's one additional term coming from the first and last vertices (which looks like it's missing from your implementation, by the way). You could either add that separately or repeat the first vertex at the end of your list. As a result, combining into the same line that defines `points` doesn't work so easily. In any case, I think it is more readable split into separate statements--one defining `points`, another repeating the first element of `points` at the end of the list and then the fold.

Edited to fix the fact that you have tuples for your points, not lists. I'm also tacitly assuming `points` is a list, I believe.

Comment: Sorry for not highlighting about inputs, inputs are in the form of tuple of list. I tried to test your code like List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).sliding(2).foldLeft(0){ case (acc, (p1, p2)::(q1, q2)::Nil) => acc + p1*q2 - p2*q1 }  . I am receiving some compile error "Constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found (T1,T2) required Int" Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming the elements of the list are tuples `(Int, Int)`. For integers alone, you'd have to switch to `case (acc, p::q::Nil)`.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like (untested)

```
val points2 = points.tail :+ points.head // shift list one to the left
val area = ((points zip points2)
    .map{case (p1, p2) => (p1._1 * p2._2) - (p2._1 * p1._2)}
    .fold(0)(_+_))/2
```

Comment: I believe the last `fold` can be a `reduce`, not that it makes a real difference. (And if it does, please tell me.)

Comment: @hoyland, reduce doesn't take an initial value, so that only works if the resulting type is the same or subtype of the element type which is not the case here

Comment: I'm reading the `map` to result in an `Array[Int]`. What am I missing?

Comment: aah indeed, i was thinking about combining the map and fold into one, but indeed just the `fold` can be a `reduce`